# Date Conversion To Year-Month In Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to convert a date (formatted as yyyy-mm-dd) to a year-month format (ex: 2021-07) while keeping the date datatype.

Coming from SQL Server, this could be done using the **FORMAT** function like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(date_column, 'yyyy-MM')
```

I am wondering how this could be achieved in **SNOWFLAKE**. I couldn't find the **FORMAT** function in **SNOWFLAKE** so I attempted with DATE, DATE_PART, but they all seem to make my column a varchar, losing its date type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equivalent of [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is [TO_VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html):

> ```
> TO_VARCHAR( <date_or_time_expr> [, '<format>' ] )
> ```

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(date_column, 'yyyy-MM')
```

Comment: This doesnt do what was asked.  It returns a VARCHAR datatype when the question explicitly asks for a DATE data type.  
Nat Taylors is the correct answer.
Compare these 2 queries :

select system$typeof(date(current_date,'YYYY-MM')); -- returns DATE
select system$typeof(to_varchar(current_date,'YYYY-MM')); -- returns VARCHAR

Comment: @Secretsquirrel Please note that the question is about the equivalent of [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-types) function from SQL Server. For your information: `Return Types  nvarchar or null`  https://dbfiddle.uk/v35AK7-G

Comment: The fact that the OP doesnt understand the output of the FORMAT command doesnt change what was asked in the first line of the question.

Comment: @Secretsquirrel First: if a column is already stored as DATE it is DATE and does not require cast `TO_DATE` as you are trying to imply but rather formatting an output.  FORMAT by definition changes datatype to varchar. Second the code you provided does not even work: `select system$typeof(date(current_date,'YYYY-MM')); -- returns DATE` If we try to perform the actual conversion `SELECT date(current_date,'YYYY-MM')` we will get:  "Can't parse '2023-05-22' as date with format 'YYYY-MM'".

Comment: @Secretsquirrel Continuing with your claim that  other answer is correct. Please check the following: `CREATE TABLE t(date_column DATE) AS SELECT CURRENT_DATE();` table that has date_column and `SELECT TO_DATE(date_column, 'yyyy-MM') FROM t;` Output:
-- Error: too many arguments for function [TO_DATE(T.DATE_COLUMN, 'yyyy-MM')] expected 1, got 2 (line 3)

Comment: @Secretsquirrel And finally, if the intention is to change the representation(no change of data type) then more correct approach is to perform it at presentation layer or by setting parameter [DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#date-output-format) - no casting needed whatsoever

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda for adding the responses. I also tried the other answer first because it seemed easier, but was disappointed and confused when it crashed with the exact errors you describe.

Answer (score 3):

`TO_DATE()` does this, like `TO_DATE(date_column, 'yyyy-MM')`  See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html

Comment: This is wrong. `select TO_DATE('2023-07-14'::date, 'yyyy-MM');` errors out.